# get ID of an object after an HTTP PUT with android + rails app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http

I am creating an Android app that can add / edit / delete projects from my Rails app.  I can successfully add projects using the Android app using an HttpGet call, but what I'd like to do is easily fetch the ID of the newly created project so that I can start an activity using the ID.  Is there a way to get a return value from my HttpGet request?

This is my Android code:

```
// Add a new user project
public class AddProjectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HttpEntity>{

    @Override
    protected HttpEntity doInBackground(String... urls){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "url: " + urls[0]);

        get.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = null;

        try{
            Log.d(TAG, "attempting to execute post");
            response = client.execute(get);
            Log.d(TAG, "response: " + response);

        } catch(HttpResponseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ClientProtocol", ""+e);
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IO", "" + e);
        }


        HttpEntity result = response.getEntity();
        String httpResponse="";

        try {
            httpResponse = inputStreamToString(result.getContent()).toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

        return result;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(HttpEntity result){
        if(result!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Project", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // redirect to activity using ID of new project ???

        }
    }

}
```

My rails project controller:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    numUntitled = Project.where("user_id"=>current_user.id).where("title like ?", "%Untitled%").count
    logger.debug("numUntitled: #{numUntitled}")
    @project.title = "Untitled-"+ (numUntitled+1).to_s()
    @project.built = false
    @project.user = current_user

    # add default project overview step
    @step = @project.steps.build
    # set step number to 0
    @step.position = 0
    @step.name = "Project Overview"
    @step.description = "Project description"
    @step.published_on = DateTime.current

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also, I seem to have gotten around this by writing another async task in my Android app to fetch the projects and get the id of the most recently created project, but this seems like extra work, especially if somehow I can get the project id from the httpput request.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Rails endpoint that this is posting to?

Comment: I added my controller action.